# Blazor upload file issue

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, stream, blazor

I'm writing a blazor server app that will sit in the adobe marketplace

I want to upload a file through the app and place it on a server

When I call the standard code for uploading a file , I get the following exception

'''

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs);
fs.Close();
```

'''

"An error occurred while reading the remote stream: TypeError: r.arrayBuffer is not a function"

I iBrowserFile onjetc has data and I can create a buffer with the correct bytes
I can create a placeholder on the server but cannot add the stream to the path Ive created

if I run the app outside of adobe , it uploads just fine

I cant find anything related to this error , is there any other way to upload a file ?

Answer (score 0):

This may not fully answer your question, but a related [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61925) issue indicates a low RAM issue.  In my case, this issue was present on older iPads but newer iPads did not have this issue.  As this happens over SignalR, this is most likely lack of browser support for handling the file.

My only solution I could find was to not support the old version of iOS that is causing this.